# LINQ OrderByDescending passing a string value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

Hi I am trying to `OrderByDescending()` on a query but rather than:

```
results = results.OrderByDescending(o => o.Surname);
```

I wish to use:

```
results = results.OrderByDescending(o => "Surname");
```

The value in quotes would be passed in in a parameter.

I was looking at reflection but am unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at LINQ Dynamic Query Library: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

this will allow you to use `results.OrderByDescending("Surname");`

Comment: Or check the C# 4 version here: http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/19/dynamic-linq-part-2-evolution.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this

```
results = results.OrderByDescending(o => o.GetType().GetProperty("Surname").GetValue(o, null).ToString())
```